# A first-year project: A small error in my while loop is driving me CRAZY. Any help greatly appreciated

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, priority-queue

The goal of this code is to develop a scheduler that works the shortest job first. I am given a `process object` that is initiated w/ `arrival time, a completion time, and a process ID number`. The timer is incremented with each loop.

The program should run on `idle` if the timer has not reached the arrival time.

If a process has `arrived` `(arrival >= timer)`, the program will loop as many times as is required by the completion time.

If multiple processes have `arrived`, I should be working through the shortest job first.

**My issue right now is that  all of my peeks and removes are contained within my `while not process_queue.is_empty():`**

yet I still end up with an error because after the queue becomes empty, I try to peek into an empty queue.

Confused as to why, and how, I am able to peek into an empty queue given the condition of my while loop.

```py
    def schedule_SJF(processes):
        """
            -------------------------------------------------------
            Description:
                Creates a schedule and an elapsed time to complete all processes using SJF implementation.
                (if >1 process has arrived, the one with the shortest completion time takes priority.)
            Use: schedule_SJF(processes)
            -------------------------------------------------------
            Parameters:
                processes - a list of Process objects pulled from a file (list) (from: processes = read_processes(filename))
            Returns:
                None            
            -------------------------------------------------------
            """
        timer = 0
        buffer = []
        length = len(processes)
        process_queue = pQueue(length, 'L')
        # initialize counter (timer), initialize temporary list to store all arrived processes (buffer),
        # initialize variable for length & initialize pQueue with 'L' mode and .

    print('Scheduling processes1.txt')
    # starting statement

    for i in processes:
        process_queue.insert(i)
    # input all data into a queue for easy use

    while not process_queue.is_empty():
        # loop until queue is empty

        if timer == 0:
            print('[Timer: 0]: Starting SJF Scheduler')
            timer += 1
        # for program start up

        elif not process_queue.is_empty() and process_queue.peek().arrival <= timer:
        # we now know >= 1 process has arrived

            while not process_queue.peek().arrival > timer:           
                buffer.append(process_queue.peek())
                process_queue.remove()    
            # create a list containing all arrived processes, break when arrival time becomes greater than the timer

            while not len(buffer) == 0 :
                shortest = buffer[0]
            # loop until buffer is empty & initialize value for shortest

                for i in range(len(buffer)):                  
                    if buffer[i].time < shortest.time:
                        shortest = buffer[i]
                buffer.remove(shortest)
                # compare all values within the buffer, isolate the value with the shortest time, remove that value.

                print('Fetching Process: {}'.format(shortest))
                for _ in range(shortest.time):
                    print('[Timer:{}]: {}'.format(timer, shortest.PID))
                    timer += 1
                # loop for as many times as is necessary to 'complete' the task

        else:
            print('[Timer:{}]: {}'.format(timer, 'idle'))
            timer += 1
        # if not timer >= arrival, program should continue looping (on 'idle')

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why you're getting an error peeking into an empty queue, let's look at your code:

```
    elif not process_queue.is_empty() and process_queue.peek().arrival <= timer:
    # we now know >= 1 process has arrived

        while not process_queue.peek().arrival > timer:           
            buffer.append(process_queue.peek())
            process_queue.remove()
```

Your problem is in that last `while` condition. It doesn't check to see if the queue is empty. The queue wasn't empty when you passed the `elif`, but the code inside the `while` removes an item from the queue. Imagine what happens if the queue contains a single item whose arrival time is less than `timer`. Execution enters the loop body, which removes that one item from the queue. Then it goes back to the conditional and tries to peek. But there's nothing in the queue.

The solution is to check for an empty queue before peeking.

Your approach to this problem is a little bit confusing. What you're doing is, essentially:

```
Add processes to a queue
while the queue isn't empty
    Remove all the processes from the queue that are earlier than the current time, and put them into a buffer
    while the buffer isn't empty
        find the process with the earliest arrival time, and process it
```

That looks like a lot of unnecessary complication.

Seems like it would be easier to do this:

```
Sort processes by arrival time
Add sorted processes to queue
while queue is not empty
    Extract the next job, and process it
```

Or, even better:

```
Add processes to a priority queue (see [heapq][1])
while priority queue is not empty
    Extract the next job, and process it
```

Comment: This is a perfect explanation as to the where my errors are and how to improve my code. I appreciate the time you took with this, just in time for me to make notes for the midterm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MitchellBrown As it sounds like this answer was totally useful to you, I wonder why there is neither an upvote, nor an "accept answer" :thinking_face: